# Why is forward declaration allowed inside a function argument list?

Tags: c++

This code shouldn't compile in my opinion, but it seems that a compiler treats `struct NonExistingNeverDeclaredType*` argument as a forward declaration ([proof](https://ideone.com/Znb5BN)). But why?

```
#include <iostream>
 
int foo(struct NonExistingNeverDeclaredType* arg) {
  return sizeof(arg);
}
 
int main() {
  std::cout << foo(nullptr) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/v3XzCw

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a property of the *elaborated type specifier*, it will introduce a declaration if the type is not previously declared:

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier)

> If the name lookup does not find a previously declared type name, the elaborated-type-specifier is introduced by class, struct, or union (i.e. not by enum), and class-name is an unqualified identifier, then the elaborated-type-specifier is a class declaration of the class-name.

It doesn't matter whether it's inside a function argument list or not. The following code is also valid:

```
class foo {
    class bar *b; // bar is not previously declared
};
```